# zf2 routing seems to ignore __NAMESPACE__

Tags: php, routes, namespaces, zend-framework2, zend-framework-mvc

In Zend Framework 2, I tried using the following route:

```
        'default' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/:username[/:action]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Website\Controller',
                    'controller'    => 'User',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),  
            ),  
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ),
```

However, when going to `http://www.example.com/MyUsernameHere`, I get a `404` not found error:

> The requested controller could not be mapped to an existing controller class.
>
> Controller:
>       User(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: User)

It's almost like the router completely ignores the `'Website\Controller'` namespace and looks for `User` without the namespace in front it.

So, if I manually enter the namespace like so:

```
        'default' => array(
            'type'    => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/:username[/:action]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller'    => 'Website\Controller\User',
                    'action'        => 'index',
                ),  
            ),  
            'may_terminate' => true,
        ),
```

then the page loads as expected.

What gives? Can the `'__NAMESPACE__'` parameter not be used for controllers? The ZF2 website clearly gives an [example](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/in-depth-guide/understanding-routing.html#generic-routes) using `'__NAMESPACE__'`, but I cannot get it work in practice. Is the example wrong and outdated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work as you expected you have to attach the `ModuleRouteListener` to the MVC event manager. You can do this in your module `onBootstrap` method:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event) 
{ 
    //...
    $application = $event->getApplication(); 
    $eventManager  = $application->getEventManager(); 
    $moduleRouteListener = new ModuleRouteListener(); 
    $moduleRouteListener->attach($eventManager); 
    //...
}
```

After you did that your code will work as expected.

They actually should have mentioned this in the page with the example that you referred to in your question. You can check for more details on the module route listener [here in the **Zend\Mvc** documentation](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.mvc.mvc-event.html#zend-mvc-mvc-event-route-listeners). They write there:

> This listener determines if the module namespace should be prepended to the controller name. This is the case if the route match contains a parameter key matching the `MODULE_NAMESPACE` constant.

Comment: This works; thank you so much. We had originally moved this code from the Skeleton application because we did not understand its purpose and wanted to bypass any unnecessary tasks.